# Laravel Echo joining() and leaving() methods are not triggered

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo, laravel-broadcast

Here is my Echo config:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    authEndpoint: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT.replace('/v1', '/broadcasting/auth'),
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'someKey',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true
});

window.Echo.connector.pusher.config.auth.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
```

In the mounted() hook of my vue component, I have:

```
window.Echo.join(`test.1`)

    .here((users) => {
        console.log(users);
    })
    .joining((user) => {
        console.log(user.name);
    })
    .leaving((user) => {
        console.log('Leaving');
    });
```

And in the destroyed() hook:

```
window.Echo.leave('test.1')
```

But only the `here()` method is being triggered, `joining()` and `leaving()` methods aren't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure `test.1` is a presence channel and someone else is actually joining/leaving?

Comment: can you share laravel back-end code ?

Comment: @gbalduzzi I am returning array instead of true/false from the channels.php. So I believe laravel treats it as a presence channel. Yes, I log in as a user and I visit (mounted) the component and leave (destroyed) the component while I am logged in.

Comment: @atouiahmed Which part of the backend code would you like to see? :)

Comment: A key piece of information is that I have my client-side app and server-side app separated. One is vue based frontend and the other is of course, laravel based backend.

Comment: the code of event that broadcast data to channel

Comment: Just to be clear, `joining` and `leaving` only get triggered if __someone else__ joins or leaves the channel, not when the actual user joins or leaves.

Comment: @gbalduzzi Thanks! You're right. It should have been mentioned in the laravel docs. I thought it triggers when any user joins a channel.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#joining-presence-channels):

- The `here` callback will be executed immediately once the channel is joined successfully, and will receive an array containing the user information for all of the other users currently subscribed to the channel;
- The `joining` method will be executed when a new user joins a channel;
- While the `leaving` method will be executed when a user leaves the channel.

So, you should use another user to join this channel, then the current user will be able to receive the joining and leaving callbacks.